# How to centre the content within a div without using margin property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a container within which i will get contents dynamically. i want all coming contents/div to be centred automatically.
i dont want to use margin property.

```
<div class="linContainer">

   <div class="content1"></div>
   <div class="content2"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: .linContainer {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: Thanks jahangir.
i want vertically centred too

Comment: Sometimes using just `padding-top` with percentage can work. Depends how accurate you want the vertical center to be, or if you want to drop support for old browsers. If you want to drop support, then use CSS3 vertical centering.

Comment: Why not use margin property?

Comment: because contents are multiples.
i don't want to separate them from each other.
thats why no margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center vertically AND horizontally, you can change the default `display` from `block` to `table-cell`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efeub76w/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.linContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note that everything will be centered (including text). Or do you want to center only divs?

Comment: Thanks Edvin.
but its making content centred only horizantly.
i need vertically too.

Comment: I see. Well, I see there are several answers already before I edited my post. Wish you good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edvin .

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.lincontainer {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `text-align:center` will serve the purpose.

```
 .linContainer{
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid red;
  max-height:200px;
}
```

You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/efeub76w/3/)

Comment: Just FYI That doesn't make **[`verticle-middle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/efeub76w/2/)**

Comment: thanks.
but if its not working if i assign some height.

Comment: yes I noticed that.Sorry it was my mistake,edited it.

Comment: @PratikN you can assign height as auto & max-height

Comment: You can center it with `display: table-cell;` Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/efeub76w/5/

Comment: Thanks.
but still it is looking like just aligned at top centred.
it should look in middle.

Comment: @PratikN please check with the fiddle provided by Vincent

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align : center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="centered-content">
        Center this!
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this too not making vertically centre.

Comment: div.align {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color:#ff6a00;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `position: absolute` idiom:

```css
.linContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

[class^='content'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="linContainer">

   <div class="content1"></div>
   <div class="content2"></div>

</div>
```

Or you can use flexbox - `display: flex`:

```css
.linContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

[class^='content'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="linContainer">

   <div class="content1"></div>
   <div class="content2"></div>

</div>
```

Good references on centering with CSS:

- [W3C - CSS: centering things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hv3)
- [CSS-tricks - Centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use css flex.

**Note: margin has just been used to define space between content blocks, not to center it.**

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-content: flex-end;
}

  .linContainer{
   background:#aeaeae;
   }

.content1, .content2, .content3, .content4{
  background:lawngreen;
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="linContainer flex-container">

   <div class="content1"></div>
   <div class="content2"></div>
   <div class="content3"></div>
   <div class="content4"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="align">
     Test
</div>


div.align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#ff6a00;
}
```

Comment: They don't want to use the margin property.